# WordPress dynamic change of posts category

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

Good day, everyone!
I wonder is there a way to create a single page for all categories and dynamically change category name in WP_query depending on a clicked navigation menu item or I have to create a separate page for every single category (there are 23 of them in my case)?

Menu:

```
<?php   
          $args = array(
            'menu' => 'category_nav',
            'container' => 'ul',
            'container_class' => 'accordion-content',
            'container_id' => '',
            'menu_class' => 'accordion-content',
            'menu_id' => '',
            'echo' => true,
            'fallback_cb' => false,
            'before' => '',
            'after' => '',
            'link_before' => '',
            'link_after' => '',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'item_spacing' => 'preserve',
            'depth' => 0,
            'walker' => '',
            'theme_location' => ''
          );

          wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```

Posts:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'nopaging' => true,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'category_name' => 'HERE GOES A CATEGORY NAME',
    );

    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    if($q->have_posts()) {
        while($q->have_posts()){ $q->next_post();
            $post_id = $q->post->ID;
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post_id ), 'full' );
            $title = get_the_title($post_id);
            $date = get_the_date('d.m.Y', $post_id);
            $content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
            $discount = get_post_field('discount', $post_id);
            $discount_exists = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'discount', true );
            $full_description = get_post_field('full_description', $post_id);
            $full_description_exists = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'full_description', true ); ?>
      <div class="gallery-item">
          <?php echo '<div class="item-img" style="background-image:url(\'' . $thumbnail[0] . '\')"></div>'; ?>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-header"> <?php echo $title; ?> </div>
            <div class="item-desc"> <?php echo $content; ?> </div>
          </div>
          <?php 
              if ( $full_description_exists ) {
                ?><div class="btn">More</div><?php
              } ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Where should I get that cateory name/ID/slug and how can I use it in my code? Should I create just category.php file in template folder or I should use another file structure to cusomize categories output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create every single page for category, you can create base file which could be used to display content dynamically. as you can see over the template hierarchy of wordpress [**here**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category) for categories which is default category attached with the default `post` Types.

***Default Category with wordpress `Post` Types.***

> Rendering category archive index pages uses the following path in WordPress:

1. category-{slug}.php – If the category’s slug is news, WordPress will
   look for category-news.php.
2. category-{id}.php – If the category’s ID is 6, WordPress will look
   for category-6.php.
3. **category.php**
4. archive.php
5. index.php

***Custom Taxonomy with Custom Post Types***

> Custom taxonomies use a slightly different template file path:

1. taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php – If the taxonomy is sometax, and
   taxonomy’s term is someterm, WordPress will look for
   taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php. In the case of post formats, the
   taxonomy is ‘post_format’ and the terms are ‘post-format-{format}.
   i.e. taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php for the link post
   format.
2. taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php – If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress
   would look for taxonomy-sometax.php.
3. **taxonomy.php**
4. archive.php
5. index.php

In your case you can use `category.php` for dynamic category display unless your category is not custom taxonomy else you will need to use `taxonomy.php` as base template.

- Q) Where should I get that cateory name/ID/slug and how can I use it in
  my code?

You can use `get_query_var();` function to achieve

**get_query_var('cat');** > This will return current category id.

```
$category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
```

And then you can get the category object by category id so you can get the 
**`cat id, name, slug etc`**

Comment: This answer is a masterpiece! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

single.php IS for all categories. Every post can use this template (except if you create template like single-$template.php) and in code you can get categories from this post by using this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: `single.php` use for single `post` or `attachments`, look for template hierarchy [**here**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post)

Comment: I agree but that solution depends on what exactly OP wants to do.